# Question about bolding math and text simultaneously

Tags: enumerate, bold, boldmath

Let me preface this by saying I am fairly hack-and-slash when it comes to LaTeX and so my solutions aren't generally very elegant. Also I will try to be specific with my question, but if you need more information feel free to ask. I am currently writing up solutions to worksheets and was wondering if there was a way I could bold the entire question (formulas and all)? My current set up is something like this:

```
\begin{document}

\item %The question

\Sol{% Here goes the solution, this personalized command changes the margins a bit}

\end{document}
```

So basically what I would like to do is have the question number and the question in bold. I believe there is a way to change all math to bold and so I figured I could rig up something like:

```
\newcommand{\Q}{#1}{*Start-Math-Bold* {\bftext{\item{#1}}}*End-Math-Bold*}
```

and just use `\Q{The question}` to achieve desired result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  {\boldmath\bfseries any text or $math$ here is bold}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It worked like a charm. It won't let me accept your answer yet, but I will once it does.