# How to boldify a part of text with maths?

Tags: bold, boldmath

If decide to go to bold mode and then I type inside maths, the maths won't be bold.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\textbf{The unknown $x$ is to be found.}

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

Of course, I could do 
`\textbf{The unknown $\mathbf{x}$ is to be found.}` but I was wondering if there is a simple way to tell LaTeX:

> Please, for this part, boldify both text **and** maths

Comment: Does [Question about bolding math and text simultaneously](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253105) help?

Comment: I deleted my answer as this is a duplicate but note that \mathbf  doesn't give the bold version of the math italic x it is bold upright roman. `\boldmath` as in the linked answer will do what you need.

Comment: I'm sure there ar cases when what you are looking for is correct, however normally `$x$` and `$\mathbf{x}$` have different meanings.  For example ***x*** may be a velocity and *x* its magnitude (speed).

Comment: Yes, it solves the question. But, is there a more "compact" way to do it? I am looking for something simple. `{\boldmath\bfseries ...` is too complicated for me. Thanks

Comment: `\newcommand\B[1]{{\boldmath\bfseries#1}}` then use `\B{xxxx $x$ xxxx}` is that short enough? (But normally you should just set up such font commands in one place (eg a heading definition) and never use multiple times in a document, so length should not be an issue

Comment: Yes I know, but I prefer standart commands. Thanks for you help anyway!