# bolding math and text simultaneously for commands

Tags: macros, bold, boldmath, boldsymbol

According to this link: [Question about bolding math and text simultaneously](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253105/question-about-bolding-math-and-text-simultaneously), using

```
\boldmath{\bfseries{}}
```

simultaneously will make both math and text bold in an equation environment.

However, if you define a new command, this does not always work. As an example:

```
\newcommand{\exampleOne}{\text{example}(a,b,\bar{c})}
\boldmath{\bfseries{\exampleOne}}
```

cannot be compiled at all. I think using `\bar{c}` prevents this way of bolding text and equation simultaneously to work. Is there a way to solve this problem and make everything bold in a math environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Note that you cannot use digits in command names.

Comment: Also, you shouldn’t say `\boldmath\bfseries{something}`, but rather `{\boldmath\bfseries something}`.  Besides looking for code snippets on the Internet, have you read an introductory guide to LaTeX? ;-) ;-) ;-)

Comment: You are right. However, even if I make it like this:

`\newcommand{\exampleOne}{\text{example}(a,b,\bar{c})}`

`\boldmath{\bfseries{exampleOne}}`

it does not work...

Comment: “It does not work” isn’t very meaningful: it does not produce bold math, or it doesn’t compile?  In any case, I did *not* say `\boldmath{\bfseries{\exampleOne}}`, I said `{\boldmath\bfseries \exampleOne}`.  You should also define `\exampleOne` as follows: `\newcommand{\exampleOne}{Example: $(a,b,\bar{c})$}`.  I repeat, read an introductory guide to LaTeX before attempting to write code in it.

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't compile. Strangely it doesn't give any errors as well. It just stays in the process of building for a long time even if I use the version you suggested.

Comment: `\documentclass{article} \newcommand{\exampleOne}{Example: $(a,b,\bar{c})$.} \begin{document} \exampleOne\space {\boldmath\bfseries \exampleOne} \end{document}` works fine on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You have to issue `\boldmath` and `\bfseries` outside math mode.  You cannot switch the math version after having entered math mode.  That you cannot switch the text font within math mode should be obvious.

To undo the effect of `\boldmath` and `\bfseries`, you can either issue `\unboldmath\mdseries` or just enclose it in a group, i.e. `{\boldmath\bfseries...}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\exampleOne}{\text{example}(a,b,\bar{c})}
\begin{document}

\boldmath\bfseries
\[ \exampleOne \]
\unboldmath\mdseries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has worked. Now I need to find a way to add this property to a description like environment.