# How to bold an entire row of text and math entries using \rowstyle?

Tags: tables, bold

Trying to follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253106/2288), `\rowstyle{\boldmath\bfseries}` doesn't work as expected to make the entire first row bold in the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,mathtools,siunitx,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

    \newcolumntype{b}{>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.5\hsize$}X<{$}}
    \newcommand{\heading}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{m}{>{\RaggedLeft\hsize=0.5\hsize}X}
    \newcommand{\rowstyle}[1]{\gdef\currentrowstyle{#1}#1\ignorespaces}

    \noindent
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{
            @{\extracolsep{0pt plus 5pt minus 3pt}}
            >{$}l<{$}
            l
            S[table-format=2.2,round-precision=2,round-mode=places, round-integer-to-decimal=true]%
            @{}}
        \toprule
        \rowstyle{\boldmath\bfseries}
        & $\delta$ [deg] & \heading{5} \\
        \midrule
        \Gamma = x^2 & $\beta$ [deg] & 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

So, what is the correct approach knowing that sometimes I compile using pdflatex and other times I compile using lualatex?

Comment: the first column is in math mode so you can not use the font change there, but also you do not use `\currentrowstyle` anywhere so the font change will not affect anything other than the first cell.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So, does it mean that I have to do it manually cell-by-cell, and there is no robust way?

Comment: you can use the array package `>{...}` syntax to insert a command such as `\zzzrowstyle` into every cell and then globally define `\zzzrowstyle` to do whetever you want that is presumably what some code you copied was doing but just defining a macro and not using it does nothing. Since you only want this for the heading rows it is much simpler just to insert `\bfseries` in each cell in that row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2,round-precision=2,round-mode=places,round-integer-to-decimal=true}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {@{}>{$\relax}X<{$}XS@{}},
  row{1} = {font=\boldmath\bfseries},
}
\toprule
               & $\delta$ [deg] & {{{5}}} \\
\midrule
  \Gamma = x^2 & $\beta$ [deg]  & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,siunitx,booktabs}

\sisetup{table-format=2.2,round-precision=2,round-mode=places}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{$}X<{$}XS@{}}
\toprule
\RowStyle[bold]{}
               & $\delta$ [deg] & {5} \\
\midrule
  \Gamma = x^2 & $\beta$ [deg]  & 1 \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]